# When is a database considered a 'large database'?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, database-performance

I have a SQL Server 2008 database, with a single table with apprx 50 columns. Primary key is a datetime. No normalisation further possible, it is simply a table storing values from different sensors every couple of seconds, so ints and decimals. 
So now, for the past month I have close to 560k rows inserted.
My question is, when would I start to see performance problems due to too much data?

To be more specific: 
My requirement so far is to display(in a chart) the last month(not an issue for this question). If I always get from the DB only the last month, a query filtered by the PK(so indexed), does it matter how big the table gets?

Ups, long rant :) Thanks for the input!

Comment: In a year you will have 6 million rows.  If a row is 1K that is a 6 GB table.  In 10 years data is nominally 60 GB.  You should be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure whatever queries you are running against your table are doing an index seek and not a scan or table scan. You can have SSMS generate a query plan that will tell you this. As long as seeks are being done, you can probably have hundreds of millions of rows and still have excellent performance.

Answer (score 1):

If your table grows 500k+ per month, this will quickly grow into a large table: in a year you will have 6M+ rows. Even though the query you need seems simple and filter the data using the indexed PK, I think you might run into performance problems.

For instance, you probably will need to to run aggregated queries on the data (counts, sums), provide comparisons with previous months, or show trend evolution for the last x months.

You might consider:

- a purging strategy, deleting older data;
- building an indicator table, summarizing the aggregated information you need for the charts.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to some of the suggestions above, to help mitigate IO churn, I would recommend making sure the date field (PK) is a **clustered** index.  This way all of the last month's records should be contiguous and easily accessible.